# Is there an efficient way of checking if HashMap contains keys that map to the same value?

Tags: java, hashmap

I basically need to know if my HashMap has different keys that map to the same value. I was wondering if there is a way other than checking each keys value against all other values in the map.

**Update:**
Just some more information that will hopefully clarify what I'm trying to accomplish. Consider a String "azza". Say that I'm iterating over this String and storing each character as a key, and it's corresponding value is some other String. Let's say I eventually get to the last occurrence of 'a' and the value is already be in the map.This would be fine if the key corresponding with the value that is already in the map is also 'a'. My issue occurs when 'a' and 'z' both map to the same value. Only if different keys map to the same value.

Comment: Get the value collection, convert it to a `HashSet`, and see if the set size is smaller than the value collection size. This assumes the value objects have suitable `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations.

Comment: After thinking this over, I think what I'm trying to accomplish is not possible without simply checking each value against all other values. For example, if I have the String "dddd". When I iterate over the String and map each character to some other String, if all occurrences of 'd' mapped to a value such as "apples", this would be fine. My map would end up with one Key, and one value. It's only when something like "ddad" and both 'a' and 'd' map to "apples"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, the fastest to both code and execute is:

```
boolean hasDupeValues = new HashSet<>(map.values()).size() != map.size();
```

which executes in O(n) time.

Sets don't allow duplicates, so the set will be smaller than the values list if there are dupes.

Comment: Subject to the caveat I mentioned.

Comment: I ended up using a Set as you and EJP mentioned, and I just had to use some creativity with a conditional. Thanks. It would be cool though if there was a .containsValue() method for HashMaps. That's kind of what I was hoping for, a library with such a function, that way I would not have to use the extra space with a Set.

Comment: @ElroyJetson what makes you think `HashMap` does not have a `containsValue` method?

Comment: @LouisWasserman's rhetorical question notwithstanding, how would `containsValue()` help? It will return true for every value (of course), so it won't be useful to find duplicates. It may be useful to use before *every* insertion to *prevent* duplicates, but you asked about *finding* duplicates.

Comment: Yes, it would be useful before insertion, and I agree that my question could have been formulated better.

Comment: I didn't mean containsValue...but a method that returns the key associated with the given value. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to EJP's and Bohemian's answer above but with streams:

```
boolean hasDupeValues = map.values().stream().distinct().count() != map.size();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `HashMap` that maps values to lists of keys. This would take more space and require (slightly) more complex code, but with the benefit of greatly higher efficiency (amortized O(1) vs. O(n) for the method of just looping all values).

For example, say you currently have `HashMap<Key, Value> map1`, and you want to know which keys have the same value. You create another map, `HashMap<Value, List<Key>> map2`.

Then you just modify `map1` and `map2` together.

```
map1.put(key, value);
if(!map2.containsKey(value)) {
    map2.put(value, new ArrayList<Key>);
}
map2.get(value).add(key);
```

Then to get all keys that map to `value`, you just do `map2.get(value)`.

If you need to put/remove in many different places, to make sure that you don't forget to use `map2` you could create your own data structure (i.e. a separate class) that contains 2 maps and implement put/remove/get/etc. for that.

---

Edit: I may have misunderstood the question. If you don't need an actual list of keys, just a simple "yes/no" answer to "does the map already contain this value?", and you want something better than O(n), you could keep a separate `HashMap<Value, Integer>` that simply counts up how many times the value occurs in the map. This would take considerably less space than a map of lists.

Comment: Yeah, I just needed a simple yes or no. I updated my question, and I'm starting to think there is no other way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether a map contains a value already by calling `map.values().contains(value)`. This is not as efficient as looking up a key in the map, but still, it's O(n), and you don't need to create a new set just in order to count its elements.

However, what you seem to need is a `BiMap`. There is no such thing in the Java standard library, but you can build one relatively easily by using two `HashMap`s: one which maps keys to values and one which maps values to keys. Every time you map a key to a value, you can then check in amortized O(1) whether the value already is mapped to, and if it isn't, map the key to the value in the one map and the value to the key in the other.

If it is an option to create a new dependency for your project, some third-party libraries contain ready-made bimaps, such as Guava ([BiMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html)) and Apache Commons ([BidiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html)).

Comment: `map.values().contains(value)` is exactly equivalent to `map.containsValue(value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the keys and save the current value in the Set.
But, before inserting that value in a Set, check if the Set already contains that value.

If this is true, it means that a previous key already contains the same value.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
Set<String> values = new HashSet<>();
Set<Integter> keysWithSameValue = new HashSet<>();

for(Integer key : map.keySet()) {
  if(values.contains(map.get(key))) {
    keysWithSameValue.add(key);
  }
  values.add(map.get(key));
}
```

Comment: That's right, we could even use `putIfAbsent` method from `ConcurrentHashMap`. We could check the return value - if it's different from `null` we add it to `keysWithSameValue`

Comment: I thought about this also. The problem is that when I add keys and values to my map, I could potentially run into  a Key Value pair that I have already added. The set would tell me that I have an issue because the value has occurred already, but really me adding the same Key with the same Pair is fine for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I never knew of this putIfAbsent()  method! Thanks!